# How to Receive IVR Voice without pressing any key to continue on call start on Twilio?

Tags: twilio

I have been using trail account. I have made a application to make a call and say Birthday greetings. I can able to make a call to the registered phone number and the message is speaking when i press a button. I need to receive the message without pressing any button. is there any option to do this? Kindly share if we can do that.

Is there any feature that makes straightforward call without prompting the caller to press any keys in dial pad ?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

The message prompt to get the recipient to press a key is a feature of our trial account. The way to remove that message is to [upgrade your Twilio account](https://www.twilio.com/console/billing) by adding a credit card or PayPal account and adding some funds.

Once you have done that, the message will go away and your call recipient will only hear the birthday greetings.